# Jekyll: sort collections by size

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to sort my Jekyll collections by the number of documents that are in each collection.

Each collection in the `site.collections` variable has a `docs` field, and the `docs` field (which is an array of documents) has a `size` field, which is the number of documents in this collection (see [documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#collections)).

However, something like this doesn't work:

```
{% assign sorted = site.collections | sort: 'docs.size' %}

{% for coll in sorted %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

It results in a

```
Liquid Exception: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

It seems that the argument to `sort` can only be an immediate field of the type of object being sorted, and not a field of a field thereof.

Is there a way to achieve sorting the collections by the number of documents they contain?

Comment: have you tried using `{% assign sorted = site.collections | sort: docs.size %}`? i.e. **`sort: docs.size`**

Comment: You mean without the quotes? Yes, then the error is `Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 14): comparison of Jekyll::Drops::CollectionDrop with Jekyll::Drops::CollectionDrop failed`.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a bug or if it isn't supposed to work like this. The [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#sort) on the sort filter is not very helpful.

Comment: Jekyll uses a custom `sort` filter. Try again with `{% assign sorted = site.collections | sort: 'size' %}`

Comment: Then it compiles, but the sort order is not by the number of documents, but the same as when I pass a non-existing field to sort, e.g. `sort: 'foo'`.

Comment: I see.. I don't think this is a bug though..

Answer (score 2):

1. Build an array of the available sizes:

   ```
   {% assign sorted = '' | split: "" %}
   {% for coll in site.collections %} 
       {% assign sorted = sorted| append: coll.docs.size %} 
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. Sort the above array.
3. Iterate the above array and all your collections printing only the collection whose size matches the sorted array number.

Comment: I know what you mean. But the problem is, an array created like this will be an array of strings, and sorting this array does not result in the correct numerical order. Is it possible to create an array of integers with Liquid?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I achieved it in a rather ugly way, along the lines of [marcanuy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47157044/4747193).

```
<!-- Create a comma-separated string of all the sizes of the collections -->
{% for coll in site.collections %}
    {% if coll.title %}
      {% if coll.docs.size < 10 %}
        {% assign str = coll.docs.size | prepend: "00" %}
      {% elsif coll.docs.size < 100 %}
        {% assign str = coll.docs.size | prepend: "0" %}
      {% else %}
        {% assign str = coll.docs.size %}
      {% endif %}
      {% assign sizes = sizes | append: str | append: "," %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<!-- Remove last comma of string -->
{% assign length = sizes | size | minus: 1 %}
{% assign sizes = sizes | slice: 0, length %}

<!-- Split string into array, sort DESC, and remove duplicate elements -->
{% assign sizes = sizes | split: "," | sort | reverse | uniq %}

<!-- Iterate through sizes, and for each size print those collections that have this size -->
{% for s in sizes %}
  {% for coll in site.collections %}
    {% assign i = s | plus: 0 %}
    {% if coll.docs.size == i %}
      <p>{{ coll.title }}: {{ i }} documents</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The main difficulty is that an array of sizes created like this, is an array of strings, and sorting it results in an alphabetical sort order, rather than in an numerical one (e.g. `"15"` comes before `"2"`).

To remedy this, I prepend `"00"` to numbers less than 10, and `"0"` to number less than 100. This makes the alphabetical sort order coincide with the desired numerical sort order.

Then I iterate through these sizes (which are still strings), and convert them to integers on the fly (by `plus: 0`) so that I can compare them to the `docs.size` field of each collection.

It's pretty verbose, but since this is executed only when the site is generated, and not at each request in production mode, it's ok.

Still, better solutions are welcome!